# Airsoft UZI gas mag not working. Is this piece supposed to be removed?

Tags: equipment, airsoft

I have a gas-powered Airsoft UZI. It does not fire. I noticed the pin on the valve to release the gas (which the trigger should be depressing in order to fire the gun) does not budge. On my other guns I can press it with my finger, but this one I can't even press with a screw-driver. I noticed this little piece of metal in there, and wonder if it is there to prevent the pin from being pressed and is intended to be removed. Any advice?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure its not already gassed? If it is, it would be really hard to press the pin in manually

Comment: @RyanS, we bought it new back in 2011 and filled it ourselves, but when put into the gun it never worked at all. So unless either it never actually got filled, or unless it has leaked out over the last 7 years, then yes, it is gassed.